# Maximum and minimum of $\frac13x^3 - \frac32y^2 + 2x $ such that $x-y=0$

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima, constraints

The function to maximize and minimize is;

$$f(x,y) = \frac13x^3 - \frac32y^2 + 2x $$

The constraint is;

$$g(x,y) = x-y $$

such that $$g(x,y) = 0$$

I found the first order condition and found critical points at x = 2 and x = 1.

The second order condition at $x = 1$ is -ve and at $x = 2$ is +ve.

So they should be maximum and minimum respectively. But my textbook disagrees. It says that $f(x,y)$ neither has a maxima or minima. Can you please help ?

Comment: So (and this might be trivial, but I am not used to the notation), we can assume $x-y=0$?

Comment: Your textbook is right. The constraint means $y=x$, so you really have to find a minimum and maximum of the function $g(x)=x^3/3-3x^2/2+2x$. What happens when $x\to\pm\infty$?

Comment: Why is this tricky, and you should note that it has neither a $\max$ nor a $\min$. It has, since it is a cubic, a local $\max,\min$.

Comment: Maybe, you are aware of a local maximum or minimum.

Comment: For these sort of problems, a good first question is "does it have a $\max$ or $\min$". Note @Jean-ClaudeArbaut's comment above.

Comment: @copper.hat And what is the litmus test for answer to that question  ?

Comment: @DivyeshShah: No single rule, unfortunately. Usually compactness of feasible region is a good check. Check if the variables are bounded. In the above, you can have both $x,y$ going to $\pm \infty$, so it is worthwhile looking at the cost as this happens.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut When $x$ tends to infinity, it goes to infinity. Similarly for the the negative infinity.

Comment: @DivyeshShah Fine. So, do a minimum and mimimum exist?

Comment: @copper.hat When you say compactness, do you mean the bound of the constraint ?

Comment: @DivyeshShah: Yes, but it does not apply here as the set $\{(x,y) | x=y\}$ is not compact.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut No global max and min.

Comment: Correct. ${}{}{}$

Comment: @DivyeshShah: You can validate that by taking $x_n=y_n = n$ and noting that the cost goes to $\infty$ and similarly for $x_n=y_n=-n$.

Comment: @copper.hat Okay, please indulge me. So even if the above constraint was $x-y = c$ then essentially it will still not have a minima or maxima? Because I can take $x$ to be as large as I want and keep y smaller by c ?

Comment: @DivyeshShah: Choose $x_n =n, y_n = x_n-c$ and similarly for $-n$ and ask the same question :-). (So yes.)

Comment: @DivyeshShah: There is no magic, just grunt work :-). I've just done it thousands of times :-)

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks :) Motivating that I dont lack some math gene.

Comment: @DivyeshShah: I lack the maths. gene, but it doesn't stop me!

Answer (score 2):

The condition is $g(x,y) = 0 \Leftrightarrow x=y$.

So, the problem becomes a simple single-variable calculus problem. You want to find the maximum and minimum of $h(x) :=f(x,x) = \frac13x^3 - \frac32x^2 + 2x$.

This is a cubic polynomial, so it does not have a global maximum or a global minimum since $$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow \infty}h(x) = \infty \text{ and } \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow - \infty}h(x) = -\infty.$$

So, your book is right.

Now, $h'(x) = x^2-3x+2$, which vanishes at $x=1$ and $x=2$. These are the local minimum and the local maximum of $h$ respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $x-y=0\implies x=y$. Thus $$\begin{align*}f(x,y)&=\frac13x^3 - \frac32y^2 + 2x\\&=\frac13x^3 - \frac32x^2 + 2x\\\end{align*}$$

which is a cubic equation. Thus $x\to\pm\infty\implies f\to\pm\infty$. Thus there are no global maximum or minimum...

Answer (score 0):

For a problem like this, you can also use Lagrange Multipliers.

We have $g(x,y)=\frac{1}{3}x^3-\frac{3}{2}y^2+2x$ and $h(x,y)=x-y=0$.

$\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}=\lambda\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}$ implies:

$x^2+2=\lambda$

$\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}=\lambda \frac{\partial h}{\partial y}$ implies:

$-3y=-\lambda$, so $\lambda = 3y$.

Using our constraint $h(x,y)$, we have $y=x$, so $\lambda = 3x$.

Finally we have $x^2+2=3x$.

This polynomial has roots at $1$ and $2$.

Check the values of $g(x,y)$ there to sort out the values. Also check $g(x,y)$ at $\infty$ and $-\infty$. Extreme values occur at critical points and at the boundary(including the ifinities).

You get the same results as other methods, but it can make problems easier with more variables or more complicated constraints.

Comment: This method gives exactly the same wrong answer as my method.

Comment: g doesn't have maxima and minima globally. It has local peaks. You need to check values at those peaks and at the extremes of your interval. This is an alternative method for finding the peaks. Once you check there, you also need to check at +/- infty. Will Edit.